# Umbraco: nodes and content are disappearing or outdated

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I'm new to web designing and have been using Umbraco to modify and update a website that my company has. I update everything in the site directly via extranet acessing the Umbraco Back Office (the admin page, by default ~/umbraco). I don't have direct acess to the server my company uses, so please keep that in mind.

Since I started using Umbraco I noticed that sometimes the nodes, content and anything else I add on the website just disappear over the weekend or after a day or two. Most of the time what happens is that the content on the website itself is updated but the content in the Back Office is outdated. Because of this, I have to rewrite everything I did.

This is an odd behavior. I tried a lot of stuff, looked for similar problems everywhere, but I can't find a solution. I tried republishing the entire site, so that cache would be deleted, but it doesn't solve the problem. Even worse is that this happens in a random way, sometimes not happening at all.

Umbraco version is 4.7.2. I appreciate any help, as this is so frustrating I think I'll eventually give up if it stays that way.

Comment: We are getting this in Umbraco 7.1.4 and 7.1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your site using SQL CE for its database?

If so, that may be the probem. Here's the discussion in the issue tracker: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4621

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the problem. I created another website using MySQL instead of SQL CE and so far the problem has not happened again. I guess I'll have to migrate everything to MySQL from the other website, however I know I will suffer on the process, being a newbie and all... :(

Answer (score 1):

try and running appending this to you URL while logged into the backend to ensure the cache is refreshed properly http://example.com/umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true , replace the example.com with your sites url.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this the same as using the "Republish entire site" option when you right-click the Content root? I've tried this before already.

Comment: Well not really as this, i believe actual will force the umbraco xml rebuild as well as the umbraco cache and the database, you could also try and install the examine index package here http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/examine-dashboard .so am i correct that its only the back-end that is out of date but not the front end i.e. if you change a property publish the front end updates but the back-end still shows old content.

Comment: Ok then, I will try that URL. However, I will not know if it worked or not unless/until it happens again, so I'll try to give an update after some time.

Alternatively, I'd like to know how this Examine plugin works. These "rebuild/optimize index" options are related to cache?

Comment: And yes, it is only the back-end that is outdated, the front end is updated. But the example you proposed is not exactly what happens: when I update something in the back-end and publish it, the front end AND the back-end are updated. The outdating problem occurs the day after, when I open the back-end and get surprised that it is outdated while the front end is updated.

Comment: @FightMeBro: This is exactly the problem that I am having. Did you have luck figuring this out? Was AdBlock the problem?

Comment: @AjitGoel Sorry Ajit for not updating this question. The answer is no, AdBlock was not the problem, since I disabled it and continue to have this same issue, at random times but still consistently.

Comment: I tried contacting Umbraco support and they said it might be a problem with the database file that was set up when the website was created. I can't change that because I don't have access to the server, I'm just a content editor. What I am currently doing against this problem is backing up every update I make for a week or so; if nothing happens in that period, then it won't happen for that content.

Comment: I don't know if this helps someone but I never got this problem after I changed from using IIS express to using IIS server.